# Floating Div's resizing issues

Tags: html, css, css-float, window-resize

I am a student just starting in Web Development. I have to create a web portfolio for an assignment.

I have a navigation bar in a div floated left. And a content div floated right which is an about me section with paragraphs and lists etc.

When i resize the browser, i get to a certain size and the right hand content div drops below. I would prefer text within the content div to just keep compressing into the div? *Note* i have to do this in HTML/CSS for the assignment as javascript solution comes later in my assignment.

I have taken all my personal info out of the paragraphs and just put in a similar amount of text.

Apologies if this is a silly question, my code will be amateurish as i am just still learning.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```css
#container 
{
 
   width: 80%;
   min-width: 1000px;
   padding-left:0px;
   padding-right:0px;
   padding-top:0px;
   padding-bottom:0px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   border: 2px solid #000000;
   background-color:#e6e6e6;
}

body 
{

   background-image: url(../images/back1.jpeg);
}

#portrait{
   float:right;
   margin-right:30px;
   margin-top:30px;
   height:196px;
   width:150px;
}
#header 
{ 
   height:258px;
   width:auto;
   color:#ffffff;
   font-size:45px;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-image: url(../images/head2.jpeg);
   background-size: cover;
   border:.1px outset #000000;
}


#navigation
{
   width:19%;
   margin-top:0px;
   float:left;
   width:250px;
   height:1400px;
   background-color:#6b6b6b;
}

#content
{
   max-width:75%;
   min-width:40%;
   padding:0px 20px 20px 0px;
   float:right;
   margin:0px;
   display:inline;
   border:2px solid #000000;
}

#footer
{
   clear:left;
   background:#e6e6e6;
   height:60px;
   color:#ffffff;
   background-color:#000000;
}
#navbar
{ 
   height:80%;
}

#navmenu
{
   padding:0px;
   margin-left:0px;
}

#navmenu li
{
   margin-right:20px;
   margin-left:20px;
   display:block;
   padding-top:100px;
   float:left;
}

a.navbutton
{
   border:3px outset #606060;
   display:block;
   background-image:url(../images/buttons/button_normal.jpg);
   text-decoration:none;
   color:#ededed;
   font-family:Tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:15px;
   width:200px;
   height:34px;
   padding-top:6px;
   text-align:center;
   color:black;
}

a.navbutton2
{
   border:3px outset #606060;
   display:block;
   background-image:url(../images/buttons/button_current.jpg);
   text-decoration:none;
   color:#000000;
   font-family:Tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:20px;
   width:200px;
   height:34px;
   padding-top:6px;
   text-align:center;
   color:black;
}

a.navbutton:hover, a.navbutton2:hover
{
   border: 3px outset #2090d0;
   background-image:url(../images/buttons/button_hover.jpg);
   color:#444444;
}

a.navbutton:active, a.navbutton2:active
{
   border: 3px inset #eecc44;
   background-image:url(../images/buttons/button_current.jpg);
   color:#444444;
}
.email
{
   margin:20px;
   float:left;
}
.copyright
{
   margin:20px;
   float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/new.css" />
   <style type="text/css">
      .green {color: #008000;}
      h2 {color: blue;font-style: italic;}
      .bold {font-weight: bold;}
   </style>
   <title>Tim CA2</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="container">
      <div id="portrait">
      </div>
      <div id="header">
         <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="content-container">

         <div id="navigation">
            <div id="navbar">
               <ul id="navmenu">
                  <li><a class="navbutton2"  href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a class="navbutton"  href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
                  <li><a class="navbutton"  href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
                  <li><a class="navbutton"  href="webdev.html">Web Skills</a></li>
                  <li><a class="navbutton"  href="pcbuild.html">PC Build</a></li>
                  <li><a class="navbutton"  href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="content">
            <p>Text       TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
      TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
      TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
      TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
      TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText<p>
      
      <ul>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
      </ul>
                  <p>Text TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
      TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
      TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
      TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
      TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText<p>
      <ul>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
         <li>listing</li>
      </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
      <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy;<p> 
      </div>
      
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/05a3g2pw/

Answer (score 0):

Without going in to the detail of your example, you are mixing width in % and padding in px. If you want your elements to react when resizing the browser (responsive) should should only use %. I see the same problem with border width. If you set the width of an element in % you should set borders in %, unless you are using css media queries to change styles at a certain width. The same goes for margin. If the width of the element is set in %, set the margin in %.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the div "text text text" on right put in your css:

```
#content-container {  display: inline-block; }
```

If you want to change the css relative the size of screen you can use @media screen, set min/max-width and create a variable display:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
div { background-color: red;}
}

    @media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
div { background-color: lime;}
}
```

In examples above when the width of screen is 800px the div elements get a background red and higher than that get lime.

In another words you can use that to put a div above another, after another etc.
I belive that can help.